# Cefsharp WPF C# Count not Find File(s) after cleaning solution

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio, cefsharp

I Pressed Clean Solution, and it cleans most of the files in the bin section/. but when I click rebuild it does not add the cef sharp libraries back.

[image]

How do I get these files back in place?

I knew what these files are and what they do. so I kept a copy of these files anyway. I placed the copy back to the location. i skipped the pdb files on purpose. it gives me an error. aren't pbd files are supposed to be regenerated since they are debugging info?

i copied all the excluded pdb files back and it works fine. but if I didn't keep that copy how would I get these lib/dll files back?

Comment: See if there's an error in that list that's not a missing file. What often happens is that you have a syntax error somewhere in the code, which prevents it from compiling, cascading the problem into other dependencies.

Comment: there's no syntax errors. when putting the missing files from my backup it works fine.

Comment: Did you added the references as absolute paths to the bin folder, or were they added through NuGet? NuGet restores the dependencies on build, but a local reference to a DLL might be problematic, depending on the VS version you're using.

Comment: @MarianoLuisVilla They were added through NuGet. I'm using VS 2019.

Comment: it's not a big problem at the moment since I had a backup. but when I push to git. these files are not present. in the future, if I ever did a git pull to another machine, I'm sure it wouldn't work since these dlls are missing. I have added bin/ to git ignore (it's 2GB+). i wouldn't rely on NuGet to re-add them

Comment: Nuget will copy the files as part of the build processes. What version of .Net are you targeting? I've not seen or had any other reports of this problem,  so you'll need to provide additional information.

Comment: Also does the problem reproduce with the minimum example https://github.com/cefsharp/CefSharp.MinimalExample